# LinuxdeployQT how to create Appimage today which will be runable on every linux distro since was released ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: c++, linux, qt5, qt-creator

I made in QT creator simple application in c++; now I tried to make an .AppImage of  my app which will be runable on every Linux distro since ubuntu 16.04 ...i tried to use linuxdeployqt but if I made an app on newest version of Manjaro I can´t run it on Ubuntu 16,18... how can i do it please TO i can run it on every linux?

Answer (score 1):

I have found that some of the automated tools are not fully up-to-scratch, so that the only "sure" way to get your application to guarantee to work on any system is to package up **all** of the libraries it needs. You can do this in one of two ways:

1. Statically link your application. I have some notes here on that subject: [static build QT App](https://forum.qt.io/topic/57888/solved-qt5-5-static-build-failed-qqmldebugserverthread-run-error-undefined-reference-to-qtcpserverconnection-qtcpserverconnection/3)
2. Package up all the libs/shared objects you need into your package, and deploy the lot into some installation folder.

I wrote my own script based around ldd to do this for me. The script it fairly old now, but should still work. Note that some plugins may need to be added manually, here I added the audio plugin that I was using at the time in the script.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Rememeber start dir
START_DIR=$PWD

# Determine which dir to deploy in and cd to that dir
if [ -d "$1" ]; then
   DEPLOY_DIR=$1
else
   DEPLOY_DIR=$PWD
fi
echo "Deploy dir: $DEPLOY_DIR"
cd $DEPLOY_DIR

# Run ldd on all files in the directory and create a list of required qt libs
flag=false
for entry in `ldd $DEPLOY_DIR/* | grep -i qt`; do
   if $flag; then
      # Only add to the array if it is not already in it
      if ! [[ $libsArray =~ $entry ]]; then
         echo "adding $entry"
         libsArray="$libsArray $entry"
      fi
      flag=false
   fi

   # If we see a "=>" then the next line will be a library
   if [ $entry == "=>" ]; then
      flag=true
   fi
done
echo 
echo

# Create the required folder structure. Note here we are need the qt audio plugin so we are going to manually copy that as well.
mkdir -p lib
mkdir -p lib/audio
# Now copy these files to the deploy directory
for entry in $libsArray; do
   echo "cp -v -f $entry $DEPLOY_DIR/lib"
   cp -v -f $entry $DEPLOY_DIR/lib
done

# Now get the audio lib - this is a plugin that we are using so we need these libs as well.
# Add other plugins here as well.
# TODO: maybe we can read this in from the *.pro file.
cp -v -f `qmake -query QT_INSTALL_BINS`/../plugins/audio/* $DEPLOY_DIR/lib/audio

# Go back to start dir
cd $START_DIR
```

Or you can try with linuxdeployqt - but the key is to make sure you have all the libs you need and local copies of them so they are the ones that are found first (and not a potentially incompatible one from elsewhere).